# Computing Median Realized Volatility: RTAQ MedRV

Tags: r, loops, xts

hey does anyone know how to loop through the MedRV function in the RTAQ package?
I have

```
##find days in data
ddx.f = endpoints(full, on="days");
days.full = format(index(full)[ddx.f], "%Y-%m-%d");

for (day in days.full) {
  x = full[day]

}
```

to extract each day but don't know what to add to loop through the MedRV function per each day.
Any ideas? And also does anyone know is there a significance test in R to test for jumps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do read the [link I gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your last question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is the same as your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051819/removing-dates-with-less-than-full-observations)

Split the data into days, and apply a function to each day.  Below `split(dxts, "days")` will create a list where each element is 1 day of data. `lapply` will apply a function to each day.

```
set.seed(123)
full <- .xts(rnorm(2880), 1:2880*5*60)
mrv <- lapply(split(full, "days"), function(x) {
    #return an xts-object, which requires a timeBased index
    xts(MedRV(x), end(x)) #use the last timestamp of the day
})
```

Then `rbind` the results into a single xts object

```
do.call(rbind, mrv)
#                         [,1]
# 1969-12-31 23:55:00  58.2340
# 1970-01-01 23:55:00 268.5672
# 1970-01-02 23:55:00 260.3016
# 1970-01-03 23:55:00 310.5664
# 1970-01-04 23:55:00 302.1562
# 1970-01-05 23:55:00 272.9567
# 1970-01-06 23:55:00 291.0333
# 1970-01-07 23:55:00 309.7571
# 1970-01-08 23:55:00 229.9853
# 1970-01-09 23:55:00 298.3878
# 1970-01-10 18:00:00 215.6014
```

**Edit/Alternate syntax**

```
mrv <- lapply(split(full, "days"), MedRV)
names(mrv) <- index(full)[endpoints(full, on="days")]
as.xts(do.call(rbind, mrv))
```

Comment: really? thanks for your help again, sorry I have so much to learn in such little time.

Comment: Are you familiar with the package at all? I am trying to test for jumps for a dissertation, but there does not seem to be a significance test

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not very familiar with that package.  You could pose that as a new question, OR you might have more luck asking about this on the [r-sig-finance mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance). (but don't crosspost to both)

Comment: I run: ##Realized Variance;
lapply(split(r.full, "days"), rRealizedVariance) -> full.obs.realized; and when I try to plot object, I get error: "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'" How do I convert it to an object with 'x' and 'y'? And do you know is it possible to take ,lapply(split(r.full, "days"), MedRV) -> full.obs.medrv from full.obs.realized so as to see the differences each day? **I have 'r.full' because i forgot to take returns**

Comment: That's because you were trying to plot a list.  You need to convert it to something printable (e.g. `unlist`).  I edited this answer to return an `xts` that you can plot

Comment: to answer your question about calculating differences, I think you can just subtract.  If you've tried and it doesn't work then create a question showing what you tried and what you expected to see.  And see that post about providing a reproducible example :-)

Comment: Hi yeah the plot worked like a dream as did the `unlist()` function, though is it true that switching to and from `xts` objects may cause your data to distort? I think the subtraction wouldn't work the first time because they were both `as.xts` but they both subtracted fine either after `unlist()` or by running your second suggested code. Thank you.

Comment: P.s sorry only beginning to understand what you had meant by reproducible example

Comment: yeah, I don't understand the question.  Maybe you want to `merge` 2 xts objects and subtract one column from another.  If you're having trouble, put together a question showing what you tried and what you want.

Comment: You don't understand my question? Basically before the significance test is conducted I need to see if there was any times that Median RV doesn't converge to realized variance so I needed to construct a time series of the two and take their differences and then to test if there are differences statistically different from zero. but so far so good after the code you sent helped me with. Now for the "easy" part and trying to compute the test statistic!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `period.apply` function, or its `apply.daily` wrapper.  I've gotten some unexpected results in the past due to the fact that `period.apply` uses `sapply` instead of `lapply` (at least I think that's why), so, I usually do it the way I did in my other answer.

```
set.seed(123)
full <- .xts(rnorm(2880), 1:2880*5*60)
ddx.f = endpoints(full, on="days")
period.apply(full, ddx.f, MedRV)

apply.daily(full, MedRV) # same as period.apply but, endpoints are created for you
#                         [,1]
# 1969-12-31 23:55:00  58.2340
# 1970-01-01 23:55:00 268.5672
# 1970-01-02 23:55:00 260.3016
# 1970-01-03 23:55:00 310.5664
# 1970-01-04 23:55:00 302.1562
# 1970-01-05 23:55:00 272.9567
# 1970-01-06 23:55:00 291.0333
# 1970-01-07 23:55:00 309.7571
# 1970-01-08 23:55:00 229.9853
# 1970-01-09 23:55:00 298.3878
# 1970-01-10 18:00:00 215.6014
```